# Why Drush cron go to view of nodes?

Tags: 8

i have a simple function to return 404 on some content-type

```
function module_type_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // variables
  $type = $node['#node']->getType();
  $userRole = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  // if is events2/subsidiary
  if(($type === 'events2' || $type === 'subsidiary') &&
  (in_array('anonymous', $userRole))) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  }
}
```

But if i run drush cron i have this error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:  in module_type_node_view() (
```

The crohn is performed anonymously, I have no way to create an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume there is something running with cron like a search indexer or something handling nodes, and since it is run anonymously, it triggers this.

Comment: ! no way of knowing if there is a "cron" user?

Comment: There is this old solution for Drupal 7, I am not sure if it is applicable for 8. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/89986/57